# Invert the rotation value in all keyframes on X and Y axis

Tags: animation, bones, keyframes

I'm trying to find a way to invert all the the rotation values on the X and Y axis on all the keyframes on certain bones.

Is there any scrip/function that would allow me to do it all at once?

I have for example X -350 and Y 50 on the hand bone I would like to change them to X 350 and Y -50 and do the same in all keyframes without having to do it manually one by one but only on that bone.

Answer (score 1):

In the graph editor set the 2D cursor in a Y loc equal to 0, turn the pivot point to be 2D cursor, select all keyframes you want to invert and press S Y -1 Enter.

[image]